# Understanding why getting each parent row joined with its latest child is not working when using subquery filter

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery

I have a parent-children tables relationship, and I was trying to get each parent row with its latest child row details.

My attempts to do that using a sub-query didn't work, and I could only made that using a CTE.

I would like to understand:

1. *Why* doesn't the sub-query way work?
2. Is there a way to fix it?

Here's a toy example of the parent-child relationship ([Full demo is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/96dc37/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE Cities
    (
        [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
        [Name] NVARCHAR(100),
        [EstablishedDate] DATETIME2 NULL,
    );
    
CREATE TABLE Parks
    (
        [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
        [Name] NVARCHAR(100),
        [OpeningDate] DATETIME2 NULL,
        [CityId] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cities(Id)
    );
```

Successful query using a CTE:

```
;WITH NumberedParks AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITiON BY CityId ORDER BY OpeningDate DESC) AS rownum
  FROM Parks
)
SELECT * 
FROM Cities
JOIN NumberedParks on Cities.Id = NumberedParks.CityId
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Failed attempts:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cities
JOIN Parks on Cities.Id = Parks.CityId
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT TOP 1 Id
  FROM Parks inner_parks
  WHERE inner_parks.Id = Parks.Id
  ORDER BY inner_parks.OpeningDate DESC
)

SELECT * 
FROM Cities
JOIN Parks on Cities.Id = Parks.CityId
WHERE Parks.Id =
(
  SELECT TOP 1 Id
  FROM Parks inner_parks
  WHERE inner_parks.Id = Parks.Id
  ORDER BY inner_parks.OpeningDate DESC
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cities
JOIN Parks on Cities.Id = Parks.CityId
WHERE Parks.Id =
(
  SELECT TOP 1 Id
  FROM Parks inner_parks
  WHERE inner_parks.Id = Parks.Id
  ORDER BY inner_parks.OpeningDate DESC
);
```

In this query, the subquery fetches the most recent (based on opening date) Park from the Parks table where the Park Id matches the outer query Park Id, however, the join in the outer query is returning all Parks, so every Park Id will get compared against the subquery, and since every Park in the Parks table exists at least once, it is always returned by the subquery.

If you want to use a subquery, you can use CROSS APPLY instead which will allow your subquery to return more than 1 row. You can then use ROW_NUMBER() to identify only the row you want per city:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cities
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CityId ORDER BY OpeningDate DESC) AS Row
  FROM Parks
) Parks
WHERE Parks.Row = 1
  AND Cities.Id = Parks.CityId
```

You can see a working [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7280fc4aed09a024887c56f8070e26af).

Comment: If you're doing an apply you may as well do `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY...`